# Регулярка для замены пробелов на запятую

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с заменой регуляркой групп пробелов на запятую, или любым другим рабочим и надежным способом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.sub(' +', ',', your_string)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 2):

Вот с помощью регулярных выражений. Заменяет блок всех пробельных символов (пробелы, табуляции) на запятую:

```
import re

x = u"abc   de\t  \tf"
print x  # abc   de     f
y = re.sub(r"\s+", u",", x)
print y  # abc,de,f
```

Answer (score 1):

можно еще воспользоваться командой replace

Comment: replace это хорошо, но как быть со случайным количеством пробелов?

Comment: вы про это не уточнили, тогда да, регулярка проще будет